# Why my VueJS Calculator does not show the numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, calculator

I was following a tutorial about how to make a calculator app in VueJS but I cannot see the numbers on the screen. This is my code in HTML, CSS and JS. I have already asked it to chatGPT but nothing to solve yet.

```js
new Vue ({
    el: '#calcolatri',
    data:{
        numCorrente: '',
        cliccato: false
    },
    methods:{
        inserici(numero){
            if(this.cliccato){
            this.numCorrente = '';
            this.cliccato = false; 
            } 
            this.numCorrente = `${this.numCorrente}${numero}`;
        },
        cancella(){
            this.numCorrente = '';
        },
        segno() {
            this.numCorrente = this.numCorrente.charAt(0) === '-' ?
                this.numCorrente.slice(1) : `-${this.numCorrente}`;
        },
        puntoop(){
            if (this.numCorrente.indexOf('.') === -1){
                this.inserici('.');
            }
        },
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #2c2929;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Belanosima', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive; 
}
.barra {
    background-color: rgb(57, 165, 105);;
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
#calcolatri {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(40px, auto);
    width: 80vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: #595757;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#schermo{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.btn {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1.5px;
    background-color: #807d7d;
}
.operatore{
background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
```

````html
```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calcolatrice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calcss.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="icon" href="Cal.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima:wght@600&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="CalJs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Tittolo">
        <div class="barra"> 
            <h1>DraCanculator</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="app">
        <div id="calcolatri">
            <div id="schermo">{{numCorrente}}</div>
                <div @click="segno" class="btn">-/+</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn">%</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn">log</div>
                <div @click="cancella" class="btn operatore">C</div>
                <div @click="inserici(7)" class="btn">7</div>
                <div @click="inserici(8)" class="btn">8</div>
                <div @click="inserici(9)" class="btn">9</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn operatore">÷</div>
                <div @click="inserici(4)" class="btn">4</div>
                <div @click="inserici(5)" class="btn">5</div>
                <div @click="inserici(6)" class="btn">6</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn operatore">x</div>
                <div @click="inserici(1)" class="btn">1</div>
                <div @click="inserici(2)" class="btn">2</div>
                <div @click="inserici(3)" class="btn">3</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn operatore">-</div>
                <div @click="inserici(0)" class="btn">0</div>
                <div @click="puntoop" class="btn">.</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn operatore">=</div>
                <div @click="" class="btn operatore">+</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
````

[image: The variable does not gets blank to set the numbers with the function "inserici"]

I would like to solve the problem and the screen gets blank to set the numbers with the button.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I copied your code and it seems to be working in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b7gzwmsx/)

Comment: See the image bellow. So it is my web browser...

Comment: check your browsers *developer* tools console for errors

Answer (score 1):

since vue can't find what it needs to init, embed the final script or refer to DOMContentLoaded:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calcolatrice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calcss.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="icon" href="Cal.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima:wght@600&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   ...
   <script src="CalJs.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```